# Transcluding Attributes in an AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs

I was creating a select replacement directive to make it easy to style up selects according to the design without having to always right a bunch of markup (i.e. the directive does it for you!).

I didn't realize that attributes don't transclude to where you put `ng-transclude` and just go to the root element.

I have an example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OLLntqMzbGCJS7g7h1j4?p=preview

You can see that it looks great... but there's one major flaw. The `id` and `name` attributes aren't being transferred. Which, ya know, without `name`, it doesn't post to the server (this form ties into an existing system, so AJAXing the model isn't an option).

For example, this is what I start with:

```
<select class="my-select irrelevant-class" name="reason" id="reason" data-anything="banana">
    <option value="">Reason for Contact...</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Pizza</option>
    <option>The good stuff</option>
    <option>This is an example of a really, really, really, really, really, really long option item</option>
</select>
```

...this is what I *want* it to look like:

```
<div class="faux-select" ng-class="{ placeholder: default == viewVal, focus: obj.focus }">
    <span class="faux-value">{{viewVal}}</span>
    <span class="icon-arrow-down"></span>
    <select ng-model="val" ng-focus="obj.focus = true" ng-blur="obj.focus = false" ng-transclude class="my-select irrelevant-class" name="reason" id="reason" data-anything="banana">
        <option value="">Reason for Contact...</option>
        <option>Banana</option>
        <option>Pizza</option>
        <option>The good stuff</option>
        <option>This is an example of a really, really, really, really, really, really long option item</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

...but this is what *actually* happens:

```
<div class="faux-select my-select irrelevant-class" ng-class="{ placeholder: default == viewVal, focus: obj.focus }" name="reason" id="reason" data-anything="banana">
    <span class="faux-value">{{viewVal}}</span>
    <span class="icon-arrow-down"></span>
    <select ng-model="val" ng-focus="obj.focus = true" ng-blur="obj.focus = false" ng-transclude>
        <option value="">Reason for Contact...</option>
        <option>Banana</option>
        <option>Pizza</option>
        <option>The good stuff</option>
        <option>This is an example of a really, really, really, really, really, really long option item</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Specifically, the issue is that there's no `name` attribute on the select, so it doesn't actually send the data to the server.

Obviously, I can use a pre-compile phase to transfer the `name` and `id` attributes (that's what I am doing for now), but it would be nice if it would just automatically transfer *all* of the attributes so they can add any classes, arbitrary data, (ng-)required, (ng-)disabled attributes, etc, etc.

I tried getting `transclude: 'element'` to work, but then I couldn't the other attributes from the template onto it.

Note, I saw the post here: [How can I transclude into an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703086/how-can-i-transclude-into-an-attribute), but it looks like they just manually transfer the data, and I am aiming to get it to auto-transfer all the attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the compile function to access the element's attributes and build the template.

```
app.directive('mySelect', [function () {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    restrict: 'C',
    compile: function (element, attrs) {
        var template = '<div class="faux-select" ng-class="{ placeholder: default == viewVal, focus: obj.focus }">' +
                       '<span class="faux-value">{{viewVal}}</span>' +
                       '<span class="icon-arrow-down entypo-down-open-mini"></span>' +
                       '<select id="' + attrs.id + '" name="' + attrs.name  + '" ng-model="val" ng-focus="obj.focus = true" ng-blur="obj.focus = false" ng-transclude>';
                       '</select>' +
                     '</div>';
        element.replaceWith(template);

        //return the postLink function 
        return function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
          var $select = elem.find('select');
          scope.default = scope.viewVal = elem.find('option')[0].innerHTML;

          scope.$watch('val', function(val) {
              if(val === '') scope.viewVal = scope.default;
              else scope.viewVal = val;
          });

          if(!scope.val) scope.val = $select.find('option[selected]').val() || '';
        }
     }
  };
}]);
```

The compile function is returning the postLink function, there are other ways to do this, you'll find more info [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile).

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ohigpHH1G8xtGTT1e5Ow?p=preview)

Comment: So then won't duplicate that ID because you don't have `replace: true` in the directive and just replace it in compile? This isn't bad. Is there a way to make it move all the attributes I put on the select over automatically?

Comment: Yes, we are doing the replacement ourselves, [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.3/src/ng/compile.js#L1237) you can see what happens in the compile when replace is true. About the attributes, I think this could be a bug because the compile [supposedly merges both template's and DOM element's attributes in the template](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.3/src/ng/compile.js#L1593). Would be fun to debug this but I need time ;), maybe you could report a bug on github.

Comment: I was actually browsing SO when you commented... not sure that's ever happened for me. I like the idea of this approach... I've always been a little confused in pre-compile land. This is like a 6 week old post, so I've waaaay moved on, but I know it will come back up again and I'll dig back in starting here. Thanks!

Comment: An slightly cleaner solution is to use `template` option with a function, instead of using `compile` function. Template function also receives the two arguments `element` and `attrs`.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-transclude` transcludes the content of an element on which the directive was placed. I would have assigned the attribute to its parent div and transcluded the entire select box in the template:

**First Approach:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/fEaJXh?p=preview

```
  <div class="form-control my-select">
    <select class="irrelevant-class" name="reason" id="reason" data-anything="banana">
      <option value="">Reason for Contact...</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Pizza</option>
      <option>The good stuff</option>
      <option>This is an example of a really, really, really, really, really, really long option item</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

And remove replace option from the definition:

```
app.directive('mySelect', [function () {
return {
    template: 
        '<div class="faux-select" ng-class="{ placeholder: default == viewVal, focus: obj.focus }">' +
            '<span class="faux-value">{{viewVal}}</span>' +
            '<span class="icon-arrow-down entypo-down-open-mini"></span>' +
            '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>',
    transclude: true,
    //replace: true,
    scope: true,
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var $select = elem.find('select');
        scope.default = scope.viewVal = elem.find('option')[0].innerHTML;

        scope.$watch('val', function(val) {
            if(val === '') scope.viewVal = scope.default;
            else scope.viewVal = val;
        });

        if(!scope.val) scope.val = $select.find('option[selected]').val() || '';
    }
};
}]);
```

**Second Approach:**
In your demo, just include following line at the end of the link method:

```
$select.attr({'id': elem.attr('id'), 'name': elem.attr('name')});
```

Comment: I know that this way would work, but the goal was to keep the markup as simple as possible. I know I can just wrap it in a `div`, I wanted to *just* markup a `select` if it was possible.