# Angularjs: how to prepend a layer into an external template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, prepend

Can I **prepend** an element into a template? For instance this is my current code which how it shows and hides a spnner div,

controller.js,

```
$scope.spinner =  base_url+image_spinner;
$scope.loading = true;

return $http({
   method: 'GET', 
   url:'server.php'
}).then(function(response) {
...
```

template.html,

```
<div class="spinner" ng-show="loading"><img src="{{spinner}}"/> &nbsp  loading</div>

<div ng-repeat='type in summaries.types' >
</div>
```

In my view, this is not ideal. It is rather tedious when you have lots of templates and you want to have a spinner in them before they are populated.

It would be better to move `<div class="spinner" ng-show="loading"><img src="{{spinner}}"/> &nbsp  loading</div>` out of the template and **prepend** it before the json data is loaded. Is it possible?

This is how load the template and the controller,

routes.js,

```
return app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
        .when("/",
        {
            templateUrl: base_url + "app/html/summary.html",
            controller: "Controller"
        })
        .when("/:module/:method/",
        {
            templateUrl: base_url + "app/html/summary.html",
            controller: "Controller"
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: what is the code that loads your template?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the template in a directive:

```
myModule.directive('nsSpinner', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<div class="spinner" ng-show="loading">' +
            '<img src="' + base_url + image_spinner + '"/> &nbsp loading' +
        '</div>';
    };
});
```

Then just add it to your HTML:

```
<ns-spinner></ns-spinner>
<div ng-repeat="type in summaries.types"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Then I still need to add `<ns-spinner></ns-spinner>` into my template after all??

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect use case for a directive. If you wanted different spinner images, you could design the directive to accept `imageUrl`, too.

```
angular.module('app').directive('spinner', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
           imageUrl: '=',
           loading: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="spinner" ng-show="loading"><img src="{{ imageUrl }}" /> loading </div>'
    }
});
```

Inside your html, any time you would like to attach a spinner to an ajax, you just have to declare a `$scope.loading` and `$scope.imageUrl`. After the AJAX returns, be sure to set `$scope.loading = false;`.

```
<div spinner imageUrl="path/to/img" loading="loading"></div>
```

If you don't like having to add the extra attributes to the directive template, you could do something with less customizability:

```
angular.module('app').directive('spinner', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div class="spinner" ng-show="loading"><img src="{{ imageUrl }}" /> loading </div>'
    }
});
```

Assuming your scope still contains `loading` and `imageUrl`, the template would just be:

```
<div spinner></div>
```

Comment: thanks. so I still have to add `<div spinner></div>` into my template??

Comment: With this implementation, yes. You could probably do a fancier implementation that implicitly constructs your template,  but that wouldn't be very 'Angular'. In my opinion, explicitly declaring your intentions in the HTML is far simpler, and easier to follow, with the caveat that each template needs to include the `<spinner>` directive.

Comment: Thanks. I just find that 'ugly' in my template with all angular hacks.

Comment: and implementing a `directive` seems to have no difference from my original option.

Comment: You could use a similar technique posted above to attach this spinner functionality directly onto your `<ng-repeat>`, but be sure to remove the `replace: true`. This isn't an "angular hack", it's the way angular is designed. It takes a while to get over the "I want my jQuery", but once you do, there's no turning back.

Comment: Thanks. Can I add that directive spinner into the ng-repeate layer like this `<div spinner ng-repeat='type in summaries.types' >
</div>` instead of adding a layer before it??

Comment: I decided against an updated answer. You probably can do that, but it's not worth the trouble in my opinion. Stacking directives like that can get messy quickly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703086/how-can-i-transclude-into-an-attribute/11704489#11704489