# AngularJS: Putting ng-transclude into a variable (ng-transclude to placeholder)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I Have a directive with transclude text I need to put it inside placeholder

My html

```
 <div ng-controller="Controller">
  <my-dialog>Hello world!</my-dialog>
  </div>
```

JS

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsTransclusionDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope,$transclude) {
    console.log($transclude);
    $scope.name = $transclude;  // I NEED TO GET HELLO WORLD HERE

  }])
  .directive('myDialog', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: 'my-dialog.html'
    };
  });
})(window.angular);\
```

My template

```
<div>this should give me transcluded text {{name}}</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your template `my-dialog.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches to get the transcluded content. [Have a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703086/how-can-i-transclude-into-an-attribute)